# boost::split argument mismatch

Tags: boost, c++builder-2010

I am trying to pass `AnsiString(someStr).c_str()` to `boost::split()` second argument but it denies showing argument mismatch!!

here is the code snippet

```
vector<std::string> sVec;
boost::split(sVec,AnsiString(response).c_str(),boost::is_any_of(" "));//err in this line
ShowMessage(sVec[1].c_str());
```

however

> boost::split(sVec,"This is a test",boost::is_any_of(" "));

works well!

Am I doing right converting AnsiString to c string type???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `sVec` is a `vector<std::string>` and not a `vector<char *>`, the second argument passed to `split()` has to be somehow converted into a `std::string` instance.

There is an implicit constructor in the `std::string` class that can transparently create an instance from a `const char *` (which is why your second example succeeds), but [AnsiString::c_str()](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/delphivclwin32/System__AnsiString__c_str.html) returns a `char *`, not a `const char *`, so this constructor does not apply.

Performing the conversion yourself should solve your problem:

```
boost::split(sVec, (const char *) AnsiString(response).c_str(),
    boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

Or, more explicitly:

```
boost::split(sVec, std::string((const char *) AnsiString(response).c_str()),
    boost::is_any_of(" "));
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither works! No match ! `[BCC32 Error] Unit1.cpp(25): E2285 Could not find a match for 'boost::algorithm::split<>(vector<string,allocator<string> >,const char *,boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>)'
  Full parser context
    Unit1.cpp(22): parsing: void _fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *)`

Comment: Template resolution apparently doesn't take the implicit constructor into account. When you say `neither works`, do you mean even an explicit constructor call results in the same error? That would be strange, since there is no ambiguity in that case.

Comment: Does the error you receive with the second code snippet say `Could not find a match for 'boost::algorithm::split<>(vector<string,allocator<string> >,string,boost::algorithm::detail::is_any_ofF<char>)'`? Which version of Boost are you using?

Comment: Hey Frederic ! It worked in the following way!! Look! It is absolutely the same as yours !!! Thanks man for help!

Comment: is there any distinction between your previous code !! I don't see it!

Comment: You're only building a temporary variable instead of passing the expression directly to `split()`. That shouldn't make any difference... but I'm not familiar enough with C++ Builder to tell if it's a compiler quirk, or something more akin to a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it in this way since `boost::split(sVec, (const char *) AnsiString(response).c_str(),
    boost::is_any_of(" "));` gives error (unfortunately)

```
AnsiString response="This is a test";
    vector<std::string> sVec;
    const char * cStr=AnsiString(response).c_str();
    boost::split(sVec, cStr,boost::is_any_of(" "));

    for (int i = 0; i < sVec.size(); i++) {
            ShowMessage(sVec[i].c_str());
    }
```